# Update One attribute in database class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with my code where I trying to update one field from database using EF Code First. I used same code in other project as I remember it was works fine, But I don't know why it's not working now.

Here is my view:

```
<p id="myElem" class="alert-danger" style="display:none"></p>

<button class="downcount btn btn-warning mt-15 btn-block" id="downcount" data-id="@Model.Post.Id"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download">Click Here</i></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.downcount').click(function () {

        var myId = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadNum", "Course")?Post_id=' + myId,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#myElem').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                $('#myElem').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            failure: function (response) {

                alert("Failure");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DownloadNum(int Post_id)
    {
        var result = db.Post.Where(p => p.Id == Post_id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.DownloadCount = result.DownloadCount+1;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Download Started !");

        }
        else
        {
            return Content("File is not on the server or deleted, Please report us to renew it!");
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug and track the process, there is no problem or error, just after database save and checked the db nothing updated or changed!

Comment: How do you instantiate db context and how lifetime scope is managed?

Comment: Have you tried to investigate queries with SQL Server Profiler? Which version of EF do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not adding, deleting, or modifying anything in the database.  I assume you want to modify/edit since you are searching for a record via this line of code:

```
var result = db.Post.Where(p => p.Id == Post_id).FirstOrDefault();

// Id is a UNIQUE property, so technically you should be using .Single()
// or .SingleOrDefault() because there should only be ONE record where p.Id == Post_id
// or you could use:
// var result = db.Post.Find(Post_id);
```

Then, you want to modify that result.

```
result.DownloadCount = result.DownloadCount+1;
db.Entry(result).EntityState = EntityState.Modified; // missing line
db.SaveChanges();
```

As a side-note, in your jQuery.. if your view is using a model.. you could change this line:

```
url: '@Url.Action("DownloadNum", "Course")?Post_id=' + myId,
```

To:

```
url: '@Url.Action("DownloadNum", "Course", new { Post_id = Model.Id })',
```

`@Url.Action` has overloaded where you can incorporate route values.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you . It's worked but this part new { Post_id = Model.Id } i got an error that can't assign method group Post_id  to anonymous type property

Comment: @FirasMsw Okay, I wouldn't worry about it as that was just a suggestion.  But if this helped please mark this answer as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered.

Comment: We should find real problem and fix it properly. Your suggestions is not good enough, EF does it automatically and you should not do it manually.